# DLLNotFoundException

Tags: c++, winapi, unity-game-engine

I am using a DLL that is a plugin for a game engine called Unity3d. I created the DLL in Visual C++ Express 2010 on windows 7 64 bit Ultimate Edition. The DLL functions properly on the machine that it was originally created on.

The problem is that the DLL is not functioning in the Unity3d Editor on another machine and giving an error that basically states that the DLL is missing some of its dependencies. The target machine is running Windows 7 Home 64 bit (if this is relevant)

Results from the error log of Dependency Walker:

> Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for
>   "c:\users\dewayne\desktop\shared\vrpnplugin\unityplugin\build\release\OPTITRACKPLUGIN.DLL"
>   contains errors. The application has failed to start because its
>   side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application
>   event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
>   (14001).
>   Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>   Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
>   Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
>   Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

The Visual C++ Express 2010 project and solution file can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1F4pP7mRSiYMGU2YTJiNTUtOWJiMS00YTYzLThhYWQtMzNiOWJhZDU5M2M0&hl=en&authkey=CJSXhqgH). The zip is 79MB and also contains its dependencies.

The DLL in question is OptiTrackPlugin.dll

Comment: "Please see the application event log".  Can't get quite more explicit than that.  Did you?

Comment: have you run sxstrace.exe? It does give you a good idea of what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Check dependencies in your dll. I use depends.exe dependency walker, it used to be bundled with Visual C++, but MS no longer provides it. You can download it separately: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed the MS C++ Runtime on the client that's using your DLL.
If you've builded it in visual studio, you need the CRT and C++ RT installed on your clients. Dependency Walker surely will detect it.

Cheers.